# ajax not loading/retrieving data

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm doing the FreeCodeCamp course and i'm trying to build a weather app.  I found a nice tutorial on how to get the latitude and longitude with geolocation.  But now when I try and run the app it doesn't seem to be retrieving the ajax data for me to parse through.  I was trying locally and moved it to hosting thinking that might have been it but now I just get a weird error on line one of my html and i don't see anything wrong.  Thanks guy here is the code and it's live on weatherapp.boomersplayground.com

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Weather APP</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="forecast">
<h1>Weather at <span id="location"> </span></h1>
<!-- <div id="imgdiv">
<img id="img" src=""/> -->
</div>
<p>It is currently <span id="temp"> </span>F with <span id="desc"> </span></p>
<p>Wind: <span id="wind"></span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var Geo = {};
  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error);
  } else {
    alert('Geolocation is not supported');
  }

  function error(){
    alert("That's weird! We couldn't find you!");
  }

  function success(position){
    Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;
  }

  var key = 'c7e3b3ac66e765aa';
  var Weather = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/"+ key +"/geolookup/conditions/q/" + Geo.lat + "," + Geo.lng + ".json";

  $.ajax({
    url : Weather,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success : function(data) {
        var location =data['location']['city'];
      var temp = data['current_observation']['temp_f'];
      var img = data['current_observation']['icon_url'];
      var desc = data['current_observation']['weather'];
      var wind = data['current_observation']['wind_string'];
      }
   })


   //setting the spans to the correct parameters
$('#location').html(location);
$('#temp').html(temp);
$('#desc').html(desc);
$('#wind').html(wind);
// filling the image src attribute with the image url
// $('#img').attr('src', img);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the variables initialised at the AJAX response outside of the `success` callback. You should use them inside the callback, since they're created asynchronously:

```
$.ajax({
    url : Weather,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success : function(data) {
        var location =data['location']['city'];
        var temp = data['current_observation']['temp_f'];
        var img = data['current_observation']['icon_url'];
        var desc = data['current_observation']['weather'];
        var wind = data['current_observation']['wind_string'];
        $('#location').html(location);
        $('#temp').html(temp);
        $('#desc').html(desc);
        $('#wind').html(wind);
    }
});
```

Comment: This definitely helped me write to the html but my ajax call still isn't retrieving the page for me to parse through?

Comment: Which AJAX response do you receive?

Comment: Nico  I got it resolved.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are treating an Asynchronous call as a synchronous one. The Ajax call needs to be in the success callback of getCurrentPosition. You are building the Ajax url before the at and lng is returned.